# Why does Spivak claim there's a definable tangent line through $(0,0)$ for the graph of the polar coordinates described by $f(\theta)=|\cos(2\theta)|$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

There is a problem in the Chapter 12 Appendix of Spivak's 4th Ed. *Calculus* (Problem 6b) that asks the reader to consider the tangent lines of different graphs of polar coordinates. For the polar coordinates described by $r=|\cos(2\theta)|$, Spivak claims (in the solution manual) that the graph's tangent line of the polar coordinate $(0,\frac{\pi}{4})$ is equal to a a line at a $45 \deg$ angle from the horizontal axis that passes through $(0,0)$. However, I think that this must be a typo.

In $6a$, we demonstrated that:

> ...for the graph of $f$ in polar coordinates, the slope of the tangent line at the point with polar coordinates $(f(\theta),\theta)$ is \begin{align}\frac{f(\theta)\cos(\theta)+f'(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{-f(\theta)\sin(\theta)+f'(\theta)\cos(\theta)} \end{align}

Note that in order for this to be valid, the denominator cannot equal $0$. From the equation $f(\theta)=r=|\cos(2\theta)|$, if $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$, we see that $f(\theta)=0$, which means that our fraction can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{f'(\frac{\pi}{4})\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})}{-f'(\frac{\pi}{4})\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})}$$

At first glance, we would claim that this equals $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})$...i.e. a slope of $1$ with origin $(0,0)$ corresponding to a "line at a $45 \deg$ angle from the horizontal axis". However, **I am pretty certain** that $f'(\frac{\pi}{4})$ does not exist.

If we consider the left and right limits of (and apply L'hopital's rule), we get:

1. $\displaystyle \lim_{\theta\to \frac{\pi}{4}^-}\frac{|\cos(2\theta)|-|\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})|}{\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}}=-2$
2. $\displaystyle \lim_{\theta\to \frac{\pi}{4}^+}\frac{|\cos(2\theta)|-|\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})|}{\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}}=2$

So $f'(\frac{\pi}{4}) \text{ DNE}$.

Interestingly, if we look at $g(\theta)=\cos(2\theta)$ (i.e. with **no** absolute value bars), even though the graphs of the polar coordinates specified by $g$ is the same as the graph generated by $f$, in this case, $f'(\frac{\pi}{4})=-2$.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

---

**Edit**: He does this again when handling the graph of the polar coordinates given by the expression $f(\theta)=r=|\cos(3\theta)|$ (where $\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}$)

...and again when handling the graph of the polar coordinates given by the expression: $r^2=2a^2\cos(2\theta)$ (in particular, when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$). Given that Spivak interprets polar coordinates as being of the form $(f(\theta),\theta)$, if one graphs $r^2=2a^2\cos(2\theta)$ (treating it as a standard expression unrelated to polar coordinates), and then implicitly differentiates the expression treating $r$ as $f(\theta)$, we will see that no such derivative exists at $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ (the slope would be $\infty$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in the limiting case. When $f(\theta)=0$, then the slope becomes (slightly abusing the notation) $$\frac{0+f'(\theta)\sin\theta}{0+f'(\theta)\cos\theta}=\tan\theta$$
As I've mentioned, this is a slight abuse, and assumes that we can simplify numerator and denominator by $f'(\theta)$ (which does not exists). But the limit of the slope exists both on the left and right of $\pi/4$.

Comment: Thank you for the input: I am not quite certain I understand what you are saying, though. Could you please clarify? What do you mean "it works in the limiting case"? Are you saying that if $M_1 \neq M_2 \text {, } f'^-(\frac{\pi}{4})=M_1 \text{, and }f'^+(\frac{\pi}{4})=M_2$, then we can conclude that $\frac{f'(\frac{\pi}{4})\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})}{f'(\frac{\pi}{4})\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})}=\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})$?

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\frac{f(x)\cos x+f'(x)\sin x}{-f(x)\sin x+f'(x)\cos x}=\tan\frac\pi4$$